# Replacing $o(1)$ by $o_P(1)$ while passing from deterministic to random

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $f(x)=o(1), i.e. f(x)\to 0, x\to 0.$ Let's now replace the deterministic $x$ by a random variable $X, f(x)$ by $f(X).$ My question is: is $f(X)=o_P(1) \text{ as } X=o_P(1)?$ That is, is  $f(X)\to_{P}0$ as $X\to_{P}0?$ **Here "$f(X)\to_{P}0$ as $X\to_{P}0$" should be understood as "$f(X_n)\to_{P}0$ as $X_n\to_{P}0.$"**

**I just wanted to make sure that the above is an immediate consequence of the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem):** so define $f(0):=0,$ making $f$ continuous at $0.$ Thereby for any sequence $X_n\to_{P}0, f(X_n)\to_{P}f(0)=0$ by **continuous mapping theorem**. So $f(X_n)=o_P(1).$ **I think this can be symbolically written as $f(X)=o_P(1) (?)$** Done, and it's clear that the statement claimed in the title of the post can be true also for a.s. and distributional convergence (**but maybe *not* for $L^p$ convergence unless we assume uniform integrability?**)

But could you please check if my argument above is correct?

Comment: Which sequence of random variables are you considering here ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon I edited the question, thanks for bringing up this point - does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ denote a random variable that is equal to $0$ everywhere, so that $X_n \xrightarrow[]{P} Y$.

Let $\tilde f$ denote the extension of $f$ at $0$, as defined by the OP. Let $D_{\tilde f}$ denote the set of discontinuity points of $\tilde f$, so that $0\notin D_{\tilde f}$ and $P(Y\in D_{\tilde f}) = P(\emptyset) = 0$.

By the continuous mapping theorem, $\tilde f(X_n) \xrightarrow[]{P} \tilde f(Y)$. By construction, $\tilde f(Y)$ is everywhere equal to $0$, thus
$\tilde f(X_n) \xrightarrow[]{P} 0$.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted your answer!